# jQuery detecting cookies enabled

Tags: jquery, cookies

I have a jQuery-based web app. My requirement is fairly simple: I want to use jQuery to find out if the user has enabled or disabled cookies in their web browser. I'm aware that there's a plugin available which can be used to create/retrieve/delete/update a cookie. But, is there a way jQuery can detect the user agent's settings?

Answer (score 41):

You don't need jQuery for that, you can use vanilla Javascript:

```
function are_cookies_enabled()
{
    var cookieEnabled = (navigator.cookieEnabled) ? true : false;

    if (typeof navigator.cookieEnabled == "undefined" && !cookieEnabled)
    { 
        document.cookie="testcookie";
        cookieEnabled = (document.cookie.indexOf("testcookie") != -1) ? true : false;
    }
    return (cookieEnabled);
}
```

http://sveinbjorn.org/cookiecheck

Comment: Easier than 6 lines of JS?

Comment: 2 lines of code bests 6 lines. jQuery resolves cross-browser incompatibilities, and is extensively tested by many developers. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2031653/59087

Comment: @Scottie, it's not so much the # of lines, but the cross-browser compatibility that you get which means you don't have to spend more time testing this solution on different browsers.

Comment: @johntrepreneur: you mean you don't have to test jQuery solutions across multiple browsers? Huh, apparently I've been doing it wrong all this time. Sure, you could use jQuery for this (though Dave Jarvis' assertion that it's "2 lines" should actually be "2 lines plus a 95 line jQuery plugin"), but adding a jQuery plugin just to test if cookies are enabled or not is something I'd smack one of my team members with a copy of Javascript: The Good Parts for doing.

Answer (score 7):

Internet Explorer (version 10, at least) always returns true for `navigator.cookieEnabled`. Here's a method to work around this:

```
function areCookiesEnabled() {
    var cookieEnabled = navigator.cookieEnabled;

    // When cookieEnabled flag is present and false then cookies are disabled.
    if (cookieEnabled === false) {
        return false;
    }

    // try to set a test cookie if we can't see any cookies and we're using 
    // either a browser that doesn't support navigator.cookieEnabled
    // or IE (which always returns true for navigator.cookieEnabled)
    if (!document.cookie && (cookieEnabled === null || /*@cc_on!@*/false))
    {
        document.cookie = "testcookie=1";

        if (!document.cookie) {
            return false;
        } else {
            document.cookie = "testcookie=; expires=" + new Date(0).toUTCString();
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please tell me, why we need to write like `(cookieEnabled === null || /*@cc_on!@*/false)` "|| false"

Comment: @Naga he is relying on conditional compilation "feature detection" (ie only) to enable (adding the '!') access  to the second block of testing for a cookie by writing/reading to document.cookie .  This is not really future proof as it is making the assumption that all browsers which return true to cookieEnabled will have conditional compilation.

Comment: @josh this fails in IE11 as it always returns true AND CC appears to be disabled in IE11 [See Demo here](http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/0dd0e22178d9f3979e976c68381e3b310394e2c6).  See Mike's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125330/javascript-navigator-cookieenabled-browser-compatibility), seems best to just never rely on navigator.cookieEnabled

Comment: i say we all just use [modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/33f00fbbeb12e92bf24711ea386e722cce6f60cc/feature-detects/cookies.js)

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way is to check the `navigator`'s property which contains the browser's information. [Reference](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch13_06.htm)

You could use `navigator.cookieEnabled === true` to detect the browser's support for cookie.

Answer (score 1):

I like this 1 liner function:

```
function cookiesEnabled() {
    return $.cookie('check', 'valid', { expires: 1 }) && $.cookie('check') == 'valid';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you testing with the property `cookieEnabled`? just try to create a cookie and check if it's done. And in case cookies work, delete the test created cookie.

```
 function are_cookies_enabled()
    {
            document.cookie="testcookie=valid";
            cookieEnabled = (document.cookie.indexOf("testcookie") != -1) ? true : false;

            if(cookieEnabled){
               document.cookie = "testcookie=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC;"; 
            }

            return cookieEnabled;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can simply set a test_cookie when loading your page. then delete if it is set, else alert('please enable cookies...');

```
    <script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function()
  {
    var TEST_COOKIE = 'test_cookie';
    jQuery.cookie( TEST_COOKIE, true );
    if ( jQuery.cookie ( TEST_COOKIE ) )
    {
      jQuery.cookie( TEST_COOKIE, null );  // delete the cookie
      alert( 'Good news, cookies are enabled.' );
    }
    else
    {
      alert( 'Cookies not enabled. Please enable and try again.' );
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: The code above is what i meant. I still do not get why my answer was voted -1.