# yii framework: display message ' Cookies are disabled in your brower'

Tags: php, cookies, yii

i m working on a project using the framework Yii, my question is: how can i display a message to the user when he tries to login to the site with cookies disabled in his browser?

Comment: Using Jquery:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112634/jquery-detecting-cookies-enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the class WebUser i have overridden the function beforeLogin like this:

```
public function beforeLogin(){
    if(!isset(Yii::app()->request->cookies['PHPSESSID']))      
    Yii::app()->controller->redirect(array('page','view'=>'cookies'));
    return parent::beforeLogin($id,$states,$fromCookie);
}
```

and i defined a static page site/page/cookies to display the message.

Answer (score 1):

Here is nothing to do with yii
Just use:

```
if(count($_COOKIE) > 0){
    echo "Cookies are yummy!";
} else {
    die( "You didn't bring any cookies here. We are hungry!");
}
```

CHeck this url: http://nik.chankov.net/2010/01/16/detecting-if-the-cookies-are-enabled-with-php/

For Managing Cookies with yii check this: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/152/cookie-management-in-yii/

hope this helps