# Detect if Cookies are enabled in IE 11 using JS

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cookies

[How to detect that JavaScript and/or Cookies are disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603289/how-to-detect-that-javascript-and-or-cookies-are-disabled)

[jQuery detecting cookies enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112634/jquery-detecting-cookies-enabled)

I tried both solutions, but IE still return true to me even if I set disabled to Cookies.

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect that JavaScript and/or Cookies are disabled?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603289/how-to-detect-that-javascript-and-or-cookies-are-disabled)

Comment: I once had a similiar problem. Found that if I opened files locally it won´t block cookies in IE11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this:

```
function areCookiesEnabled() {
    try {
      document.cookie = 'cookietest=1';
      var cookiesEnabled = document.cookie.indexOf('cookietest=') !== -1;
      document.cookie = 'cookietest=1; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT';
      return cookiesEnabled;
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
}
```

From [Modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr) library